# How to skip all callbacks except paper-trail when updating an ActiveRecord model using update_column method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, rubygems, paper-trail-gem, database-versioning

I am new to rails. I want to track the versions of my record using paper_trail gem but I am not able to do so when I use the update_columns method. I think overriding the update_columns method may help me but I don't know how exactly should I write the code?

Answer (score 1):

> How to skip all callbacks except paper-trail when updating an ActiveRecord model using update_column method? .. I use the update_columns method.

Per the [Rails docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_columns), the `update_columns` method skips callbacks. This includes the callbacks installed by PT.

> I am new to rails. ... I think overriding the update_columns method may help me ..?

If you're new to rails, you should not override core rails methods.

#### Solutions

In descending order of preference:

1. Normally, I'd recommend using `update` instead of `update_columns`. But, you want to skip a [proper subset](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/proper_subset) of callbacks.
2. You can [`touch`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-touch) the record, and PT will record a `Version` in which only `updated_at` changed. If you only need `object` and not `object_changes`, this is sufficient.
3. You can use `PaperTrail::Version.create` just like any other model. This is public API, but you're responsible for passing the correct attributes.
4. You can use `PaperTrail::RecordTrail#record_update`. This is private API and is subject to change at any time without warning.